# Is there a way to merge spark-submit command line args with SparkConf() settings in code?

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am trying to load a jar file for my spark job.

I had been doing something like...

```
jar_file = "my.jar"

spark_config = (
   SparkConf()
   .setAppName("test_app")
   .set("spark.jars", jar_file)
)

spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=spark_config).getOrCreate()
```

And that has worked. I am able load and use the jar file.

The concern I have is what happens when a user does `spark-submit --jars other.jar main.py`

I want to make sure that it loads both jars (the one that I am specifying in code, my.jar, along with the jar that the user is passing in the command line, other.jar).

Reading the docs, https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

> Any values specified as flags or in the properties file will be passed on to the application and merged with those specified through SparkConf. **Properties set directly on the SparkConf take highest precedence, then flags passed to spark-submit or spark-shell, then options in the spark-defaults.conf file.** A few configuration keys have been renamed since earlier versions of Spark; in such cases, the older key names are still accepted, but take lower precedence than any instance of the newer key.

I was trying to figure out if there is a way to read what is sent in the command line before setting up the `SparkConf` in code, but those command line values do not look to be available until after the `SparkSession.getOrCreate()` and I don’t think that I can change these settings once that has happened.

Any thought on how to handle a use case wanting to send in a jar and me wanting to set a jar for all use cases?